# Krishna Driving Chariot Away While Fighting Karna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, karna

I want to know if Krishna had drove the chariot away while arjuna fought with Karna. This is shown in Suryaputra Karn and also in the Star TV Mahabharata.

But, is it true?

Comment: Yes it is true. Actually Karna acquired a very powerful weapon called 'Shakti' from Indra. Karna would everyday come to battlefield thinking he would use it against Arjuna. So to save Arjuna Krishna used to somehow drive the chariot away from Karna. Finally Karna was forced to use this weapon against Ghatotkach.This weapon could be used only once. So then Arjuna defeated and killed Karna .

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande  Indu forgot to mention that this indecent happens after Ghatotkach deth he said about Yesterday's Episode of Surya putra karna.....final war of Arjuna & karna

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande: Yes, you are right. The same was shown differently in Ramanand Sagar's Krishna serial and B R Chopra's Mahabharat.

Answer (score 1):

On the 17th day, Arjuna and Karna are face to face. Karna uses Bhargavastra against Pandava army. Arjuna is not unable to counter this weapon. So Krishna told him to withdraw temporarily. They visited Yudhishthira who was outside the battlefield, wounded by the weapons of Karna.

But after insulted by Yudhishthira for retreating, Arjuna returned to the battlefield. Now both of them are face to face with each other once again.

To know more about Suryaputra Karna and his death, read the complete article:

https://mythgyaan.com/suryaputra-karna-death/

Comment: Appreciate your work.

Comment: Can you show where in Mahabharata is this mentioned? Most of the content you have writen in the source link is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was real .i had searched full details about many occasions of the war for nearly 2 years and still doing it on the day of karna's death (17th day of kurukshetra war) ARJUN came to the battlefield with a strong team of warriors with him ,they were Bheem immediately behind him ,nakul in his left ,sahadev dhrishtathuyman in his right ,and some other powerful warriors with him and krishna driving the chariot (who can save arjun at any cost)and hanuman's insigna in his chariot flag which resembles that he got hanuman's eternal support too apart from his ARCHERY SKILL AND GANDIVA but unlike arjun KARNA came to the battle field with his elder SON VRISHASENA who is a terrible warrior like his father (in a duel with ARJUN he pierced arjun in his lefthand and krishna in left shoulder) he is mentioned as a MAHARATHI by BHISHMA and he was even powerful than ABHIMANYU who was tutored by krishna,while vrishasena by his own father GREAT KARNA but unfortunately arjun killed him on the same day of karna's death to take revenge for abhimantu's death karna had his other two sons near his chariot (they too trained by karna) together they heading towards arjuns troop unlike arjun KARNA believed in his skill even more than his vijaya bow and his kavach kundal on the previous day(16th day) and the present day karna showed a thundering skill of archery which never showed by anyone in karna parva of mahabharath krishna says to arjun "OH MY DEAR FRIEND THE MAN STANDING INFRONT IS A LION IN TEXTURE AND A DESTROYER LIKE LORD SHIVA HIMSELF HE IS EITHER EQUAL TO YOU OR SUPERIOR TO YOU IT IS IMPOSSIBLE YOU TO BEAT HIM"So krishna is in a hurry to kill karna eventhough in adharma way so he drove the chariot from karna's chariot who nearly going to kill arjun within a minute as he want karn to chase him and got his chariot wheel struck in mud and the rest is HISTORY .